# Why does typescript show an error for my more specific type

Tags: typescript, types

I am working on creating a generic api handler for an API I am creating/working with.

I have defined types for all the possible ways an endpoint could be referenced, and am now working on creating objects for each endpoint.

I created a generic Proxy based solution for actually calling the api (only some of it is shown below).

This is just for example, as this is split among different namespaces and files.

The problem I have is when I start to assign the possible routes to my `ApiService`, I get a type error.

```
Type 'IRoute' is not assignable to type 'IApiService'.
Property 'TestItem' is missing in type 'IRoute'.
```

I do not understand why `TestItem` is "missing" as on `IRoute` I have a generic key, and `TestItem` matches the generic `[string]: IRoute` index.

Maybe I am missing something. I could just `return return makeApiProxy("/api") as any;` to clear the error, but I try not to do that and I would prefer to understand what mechanism I am misunderstanding.

```
type WithParamsQueryBody<Params extends any[], Query, Body, Response> = (params: Params, query: Query, body: Body) => Promise<Response>;
type WithBody<Body, Response> = (body: Body) => Body;
type WithParams<Params extends any[], Response> = (params: Params) => Promise<Response>;
type WithParamsBody<Params extends any[], Body, Response> = (params: Params, body: Body) => Promise<Response>;
type WithParamsQuery<Params extends any[], Query, Response> = (params: Params, query: Query) => Promise<Response>;
type WithQuery<Query, Response> = (query: Query) => Promise<Response>;
type WithNone<Response> = () => Promise<Response>;
type UnknownApiCall = (...params: any[]) => any;

interface IRoute {
    Delete?: WithParams<any[], any> | WithParamsQuery<any[], any, any> | WithQuery<any, any>;
    Get?: WithParams<any[], any> | WithParamsQuery<any[], any, any> | WithQuery<any, any> | WithNone<any>;
    Patch?: WithBody<any, any> | WithParamsBody<any[], any, any> | WithParamsQueryBody<any[], any, any, any>;
    Post?: WithBody<any, any> | WithParamsBody<any[], any, any> | WithParamsQueryBody<any[], any, any, any>;

    [key: string]: IRoute | Function;
}

interface ITestItemRoute extends IRoute {
    Get: WithQuery<any, any[]> & WithParams<[number], any>;
    Post: WithBody<any, any>;
    SubItem: {
        Get: WithParams<[number], any[]>;
        Post: WithBody<any, any>;
    };
}

interface IApiService {
    TestItem: ITestItemRoute;
}

function ApiService($http: any): IApiService {
    function ApiGet(path: string) {
        return (...args: any[]) => {
            return $http.get(path, args);
        };
    }

    function ApiPost(path: string) {
        return (...args: any[]) => {
            return $http.get(path, args);
        };
    }

    function makeApiProxy(path: string): IRoute {
        return new Proxy({}, {
            get: (target, name) => {
                switch (name) {
                    case "Get":
                        return ApiGet(path);
                    case "Post":
                        return ApiPost(path);
                    default:
                        return makeApiProxy(`${path}/${name}`);
                }

            },
        });
    }

    /**
     * Type 'IRoute' is not assignable to type 'IApiService'.
     * Property 'TestItem' is missing in type 'IRoute'.
     * 
     * But why? IRoute has the generic [key: string] index on it!
     */
    return makeApiProxy("/api");
}


// We would pass in our $http service
const api = ApiService({} as any);

api.TestItem.Get([12]).then((testItem: any) => console.log(testItem));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instructive to strip this down to the specific problem you're asking about:

Let's look at two interfaces: `I` has an index signature for `number` properties, and `O` is a more "plain" object with two `number` properties with keys named `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

```
interface I {
  [key: string]: number;
}
interface O {
  foo: number;
  bar: number;
}
```

Watch as we fail to assign a value of type `I` to a variable of type `O`:

```
declare let i: I;
let o: O = i; // error: 
// Type 'I' is not assignable to type 'O'.  
// Property 'foo' is missing in type 'I'.
```

The complaint is that `"foo"` is missing in type `I`.  Doesn't the index signature help?  No.  For this reason:

```
const goodIbadO = { baz: 4 };
i = goodIbadO; // okay 
o = goodIbadO; // error
```

You see, `goodIbadO` is a perfectly valid `I`, because `"baz"` is some string key and the property is a `number` value.  But it is absolutely *not* an acceptable `O`, because it is missing the requisite `"foo"` and `"bar`"` keys.

And since not every `I` is an `O`, you can't assign an `I` value to an `O` variable in general.

---

And, for the same reason, `IRoute` is not assignable to `IApiService`.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. To summarize, you can assign something specific to something more generic, but not generic to more specific.